# Reducing box size

Tags: python

The problem I've been given is that I'm supposed to make a box in python that continually decreases in size till it reaches zero. I'm able to make the box just fine but I'm not sure how to make it smaller.

```
box_size=input("box_size:" )
box_size=int(box_size)
for row in range(box_size):
    for col in range(box_size*2):
     print('*',end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Think about how you could use a loop to decrease `box_size`.

Comment: Please add an example of your desired output.

Comment: https://pynative.com/python-range-function/ You want you use ```for i in range(box_size, 0, -1)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an outer for loop, which goes from `box_size` to `0`
You can also use overloaded `*` to create `idx*2` stars instead of the innermost for loop

```
box_size=input("box_size:" )
box_size=int(box_size)

#Outer for loop which goes from box_size to 0
for idx in range(box_size,0,-1):
    #Use the size to print the box
    for row in range(idx):
        #Using overloaded multiplication to create idx*2 *
        print('*'*idx*2,end='')
        print()
    print()
```

An output might look like

```
box_size:5
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********

********
********
********
********

******
******
******

****
****

**
```